# Define a custom function that can be applied to anentire column or sequence of integers (R)

Tags: r

I looked around for a solution, but I'm not sure how to ask this. I want to define a function in R that has only one argument but can be applied to a whole column.

I tried the following (simplified) code:

```
my_function <- function(x) {
    if (x <= 75){
        return(0.793)
        }
    else {
        return(0.956)
        }       
}
```

This works nicely when `x` takes a single numeric value. However, I would like to evaluate the following:

```
my_function(seq(from = 1, to = 1500, by = 1))
```

I don't know how to specify that x could be a vector when defining the function T01 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse` is a builtin R function that can apply this kind of logic to vectors:

```
ifelse(c(70:80) <= 75, 0.793, 0.956)
```

Output:

```
# [1] 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.956 0.956 0.956 0.956 0.956
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
my_function <- function (X) {
  X[X <= 75L] <- .793
  X[X > 75L] <- .956
  X
}
my_function(100)
# [1] 0.956
my_function(c(70:80))
#  [1] 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.956 0.956 0.956 0.956 0.956
```

Comment: Very elegant. Thank you. What does the L stand for? I've seen it in my environmen when I make a for loop, but it's never been clear to me what it stands for.